# How to make Swipe to refresh using json in android?

Tags: android

I have an application contain listview and have swipe to refresh.
Problem :- In oncreate method I executed Url and have footer named as "load more" ,on first Request to server I will show 5 list items like:- recordCount=5,lastcount=0,when user click on "load more" send request like recordCount=5,lastCount=5 same as another click recordCound will remain same and LastCount incremented by 5.what I want when swipe to refresh RecordCound will become 5 and lastCount will become 0.How can I do that

here is code:-

```
    private int m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// intiallly record count is 5.
private int m_n_DeafalutLastCount = 0;//initally lastcount is 0.

private String sz_RecordCount;// //declaring String record count variable variable
private String sz_LastCount;//declaring String lastcount  variable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_listing, container, false);//intialize mainLayout
    getDetails();// get deatail of user from sharedpreference......
    init();//initialize metho
    return m_Main;
}

private void getDetails() {// get details of user from shared preference...
    CLoginSessionManagement m_oSessionManagement = new CLoginSessionManagement(getActivity());// crating object of Login Session
    HashMap<String, String> user = m_oSessionManagement.getLoginDetails();// get String from Login Session
    m_szMobileNumber = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_MOBILE).trim();// getting password from saved preferences..........
    m_szEncryptedPassword = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_PASSWORD).trim();// getting mobile num from shared preferences...
    System.out.println("Deal Mobile:-" + m_szMobileNumber);
    s_oDataset = new ArrayList<>();// making object of Arraylist


    new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);// execute Url to fetch Deal list from serevr.

}

private void init() {// initialize controls
    m_connectionText = (TextView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.notransaction_message);
    m_connectionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    m_LoadMoreProgressView = (CircularProgressView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);// finding Id of progressview
    m_LoadMoreProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);// make profressView Invisible first time
    mSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
    mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            m_ListView.removeFooterView(btnLoadMore);
            s_oDataset.clear();
            new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);// execute Url to fetch Deal list from serevr.


        }
    });
    m_n_FormImage = new int[]{// defining Images in Integer array
            R.drawable.amazon,
            R.drawable.whatsapp,
            R.drawable.zorpia,
                R.drawable.path,
                R.drawable.app_me,
                R.drawable.evernote,
                R.drawable.app_me};

        m_ListView = (ListView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.dealList);// findind Id of Listview
        m_ListView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
        m_ListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem==0){
                    mSwipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else{
                    mSwipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// increment of record count
        sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// increment of last count...

}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private String DealListing(String url) {// this method POST details of user to server
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

            Log.d(TAG, "Server Request:-" + json);
        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = entity.getContent();

            Log.d(TAG, "InputStream:-" + inputStream.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Response:-" + httpResponse.toString());


        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();

            Log.d(TAG, "Status Code:-" + statusLine);

        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            s_szresult = CJsonsResponse.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

                Log.d(TAG, "Server Response:-" + s_szresult);
        } else
            s_szresult = "Did not work!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Response Password:" + m_szEncryptedPassword);
    Log.d(TAG, "Record Count:" + sz_RecordCount);
    Log.d(TAG, "Last count:-" + sz_LastCount);
    // 11. return s_szResult
    return s_szresult;
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
private void getResponse() throws JSONException {// getting response from serevr ..................
    if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
    } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());

    }else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Technical Failure")){
        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout),"Technical Failure",getActivity());
    }
}

//  sending deal data to server and retreive Deal list......
class CDealDataSent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public CDealAppDatastorage item;// declaring DealAppdataStorage
    SpotsDialog dialog = new SpotsDialog(getActivity(),"Please wait while loading");
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return DealListing(urls[0]);// sending data to server...

    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {// this method Update UI
        mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        dialog.dismiss();
        try {
            m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
            JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response


            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
                item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
                item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
                s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

            }

                // LoadMore button
                btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());// creating button
                btnLoadMore.setText("LOAD MORE DEALS");// set Text in Button
                btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_boarder);// set Background Resource
                btnLoadMore.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Medium);// setting Text appearence of button text
                btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);// set Color of button text
                btnLoadMore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);// set Gravity of button text



            if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {// condition if data in arraylist is not empty
                // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
                m_ListView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);// add footer in listview
                m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// notify adapter about changes in List
            } else {
                btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);// else Load buttonvisibility set to Gone
            }
            btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {// load more button onclick listener
                    m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                    m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above
                    String itemscount = String.valueOf(m_ListView.getAdapter().getCount());
                    System.out.println("Toatal item:-"+itemscount);

                    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                    new DealNext().execute(m_DealListingURL);// POST DATA TO SERVER TO LOAD MORE DATA......
                }
            });

            getResponse();// get response from server....
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

//  sending data and receive reponse on second hit T LOAD MORE DATA  when show more Btn  clicked..............
private class DealNext extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        m_LoadMoreProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// SHOW PROGRESS BAR
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //My Background tasks are written here
        synchronized (this) {
            return DealListing(urls[0]);// POST DATA TO SERVER
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        m_LoadMoreProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);// DISMISS PROGRESS BAR..........

        try {
            m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
            final JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");// GETTING DEAL LIST
            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));//getting deal name
                item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// getting deal code
                item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));

                if (!s_oDataset.contains(item)) {
                    s_oDataset.add(item);
                }
            }
            // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
            int currentPosition = m_ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);
            m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);
            // Setting new scroll position
            m_ListView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

            getResponse();// getting response from server.....and also here response based logics...


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you get it working ?

Comment: in `mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener` simply set `sz_LastCount = 0`.

Comment: Thanks It works Janki ....